# Nested Python while loops for vector comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a function `part` that produces arrays of numbers of length `n*k` randomly but subject to a certain distribution. I also have a function `check_diff` that returns `True/False` accodring to a certain measure of similarity betweeen such vectors; this is not really relevant. I want to build a function `output` that creates 1000 such vectors, then takes the first in the list (`potential[0]`) and puts it to a new list `final`. Then it seeks another vector `v` in `potential` that `check_diff(potential[0], v) == 1`. If this is the case, the vector is appended to `final`. Now, I want to seek another vector `v1` in `potential` such that `check_diff(potential[0], v1) == 1` and `check_diff(v, v) == 1`. When this is the case `v1` is appended to final, etc.

This is a very basic looping question, but somehow I cannot get my head around it. Here's the snippet code.

```
def output(n,k):
    potential = [part(n,k) for i in range(1000)]
    final = [potential[0]]
    i = 0
    while(i in range(len(potential))):
        j = 0
        while(j in range(len(final))):
            if check_diff(final[j], potential[i]) == 0:
                potential.remove(potential[i])
                break
            if check_diff(final[j], potential[i]) == 1:
                final.append(potential[i])
    return final
```

EDIT: Let me add another attempt, however still does not work:

```
def output(n, k):
    potential = [part(n, k) for i in range(300000)]
    final = [potential[0]]

    i=1
    while(i < len(potential)):

        for j in range(len(final)):
            temp = []
            if check_diff(final[j], potential[i]) == 1:
                temp.append(1)
            if sum(temp) == len(final):
                final.append(potential[i])
                potential.remove(potential[i])
        i = i + 1
    return final
```

Comment: You never update neither `i` inside the `while(i)` loop nor `j` inside the `while(j)`.

Comment: You should replace your `while` loops with `for` loops. Also move the statement `if check_diff(final[j], potential[i]) == 1` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @toti08, why would ```for``` be beneficial here? Thanks.

Comment: Because the way you are using your `while` loop is not correct, and if you want to iterate through all values in `range(len(potential))` you should use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update `i` and `j` ,and also your syntax is kind of mixed of `for` and `while`.
this is how you can fix this:

```
def output(n,k):
    potential = [part(n,k) for i in range(1000)]
    final = [potential[0]]
    i = 0
    while(i < len(potential)):
        j = 0
        while(j < len(final)):
            if check_diff(final[j], potential[i]) == 0:
                potential.remove(potential[i])
                break
            
            if check_diff(final[j], potential[i]) == 1:
                final.append(potential[i])
            j += 1

        i += 1
    return final
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow it still gives duplicated entries and for such ```check_diff``` returns 0.

Comment: but it helps you with your "out of range" problem , pls check the green mark near my answer @RobertBarg